# jQuery selection issue from within div containers

Tags: jquery

**Update:** I'd add IDs but it would take me a few hours to change the system I'm working with, is there any other way to do this, such as an index of some sort, or by the power of `this`?

So I have multiple containers in the following format (around 5ish **inner_groups** all in the same format):

```
<div class="inner_group">
    <div class="section">
        <select onchange="get_font_weights_list(this);">
            <option>Font 1</option>
            <option>Font 2</option>
            <option>Font 3</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div class="section">
        <select>
            <option>Font Weight 1</option>
            <option>Font Weight 2</option>
            <option>Font Weight 3</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="inner_group">
    <div class="section">
        <select onchange="get_font_weights_list(this);">
            <option>Font 1</option>
            <option>Font 2</option>
            <option>Font 3</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div class="section">
        <select>
            <option>Font Weight 1</option>
            <option>Font Weight 2</option>
            <option>Font Weight 3</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
```

Upon choosing a font from the select, I populate the font weights, they have 3 weights to begin with but I add more dependant on the font. The problem is that it works fine for the first container, but say I choose a font from the second container `inner_group` it populates the first container's font weights.

I was trying to do something like this within **get_font_weights_list** but it doesn't work:

```
jQuery(font).parent().parent().parent().parent().(".section select:nth-child(4)").append(result);
```

Results is just a bunch of font weight options.

I'm passing in `this` to the function so maybe I can pull in a reference or index from that? I really can't seem to figure this out. As I said it works perfect when clicking on the first selection but not any of the others.

Comment: that's why `id` comes in handy.

Comment: You can have the id tag as index.. and in the selector select by that index (or "somename"+index)

Comment: At three `.parent()` calls you would already be outside of the HTML you have in your question.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the number of options you have, rather than dynamically modifying the value, you could pre-populate your HTML with all of the possible values, and only show the "current" values.

```
<div class="section">
  <select></select>
  <select class="hide"></select>
  <select class="hide"></select>
  <select class="hide"></select>
  <select class="hide"></select>
</div>
```

Then you can do something like:

```
index = this.selectedIndex;
$('.section').find('> select').addClass('hide').eq(index).removeClass('hide')
```

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution, it seems using '.find' works, so I came up with this:

```
jQuery(font).parent().parent().find('> .section:nth-child(5)').addClass('active');
```

I'm sure it could be cleaner rather than using .parent.parent.parent (will update once I find a cleaner solution, or if anybody knows one I tried parentsUntil but it didn't seem to work, not sure why...)